# Why do I always get ErrorInvalidRequest for DeleteItem EWS Operation?

Tags: javascript, exchangewebservices, office-addins

I'm trying to use the EWS DeleteItem operation, and here's how I'm calling it:

```
var mailbox = Office.context.mailbox;
var item = Office.cast.item.toItemRead(mailbox.item);
var requestResponse = mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync(getDeleteItemRequest(item.itemId), callback2);
```

Here is my getDeleteItemRequest function:

```
function getDeleteItemRequest(id) {
    var result = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> ' +
        '<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:t="https://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"> ' +
        '<soap:Body> ' +
        '<DeleteItem DeleteType="HardDelete" xmlns="https://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"> ' +
        '<ItemIds> ' +
        '<t:ItemId Id="' + id + '" /> ' +
        '</ItemIds> ' +
        '</DeleteItem> ' +
        '</soap:Body> ' +
        '</soap:Envelope>';

    return result;
}
```

But, I always get back ErrorInvalidRequest and the item is never deleted.
It is Exchange 2013 that I'm using. Why is this failing to delete the item?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DeleteItem isn't allowed in an Addin, only a subset of EWS Request are they are listed in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/web-services. You can use MoveItem or set a specific retention tag on the Item as an alternative.

In you request the XML schema definitions are wrong Microsoft did a mass update on the documentation and broke most EWS request (the changed http to https in the schema declaration which the server won't accept) so your request

```
function getMoveItemRequest(id, changeKey) {
var result =
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> ' +
    '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ' +
        'xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ' +
        'xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" ' +
        'xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"> ' +
    '<soap:Header> ' +
        '<t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" soap:mustUnderstand="0" /> ' +
    '</soap:Header> ' +
    '<soap:Body> ' +
        '<MoveItem xmlns="https://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" ' +
            'xmlns:t="https://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"> ' +
            '<ToFolderId> ' +
                '<t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="deleteditems"/> ' +
            '</ToFolderId> ' +
            '<ItemIds> ' +
                '<t:ItemId Id="' + id + '" ChangeKey="' + changeKey + '"/> ' +
            '</ItemIds> ' +
        '</MoveItem> ' +
    '</soap:Body> ' +
    '</soap:Envelope> ';

return result;
```

}

should be

```
function getMoveItemRequest(id, changeKey) {
var result =
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> ' +
    '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ' +
        'xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ' +
        'xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" ' +
        'xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"> ' +
    '<soap:Header> ' +
        '<t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" soap:mustUnderstand="0" /> ' +
    '</soap:Header> ' +
    '<soap:Body> ' +
        '<MoveItem xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" ' +
            'xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"> ' +
            '<ToFolderId> ' +
                '<t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="deleteditems"/> ' +
            '</ToFolderId> ' +
            '<ItemIds> ' +
                '<t:ItemId Id="' + id + '" ChangeKey="' + changeKey + '"/> ' +
            '</ItemIds> ' +
        '</MoveItem> ' +
    '</soap:Body> ' +
    '</soap:Envelope> ';

return result;
```

}

Comment: Thank you for the response Glen! However, when I use the MoveItem operation, I face the same problem - I'm still getting back the ErrorInvalidResponse. Here is my MoveItem SOAP request: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aCn-Q4YXLimooPC2BN00B_S-zCHtoxDd/view?usp=sharing      (sorry about posting a link - I didn't have enough room to put the code in this comment!) Any ideas on this? I can show you how I'm getting the ChangeKey as well, if you'd like.

Comment: Does it work if you move to a folder other then the deletedItems ? I'm pretty sure that move isn't valid for the same reason DeleteItem isn't allowed its about the security issues around rouge apps being able to delete data.

Comment: I've tried moving it to junkemail and got the same ErrorInvalidRequest. I also opened an email from inside the deleted items folder and tried moving it to the inbox and still got the same response. Any other ideas?

Comment: You schema definition in MoveItem is not correct they are based on the documentation which is now wrong (eg you can check the services.wsdl to confirm all EWS SOAP schema definition use http not https note this doesn't related to the underlying protocol it is just a XML thing).

Comment: You were right! That fixed the problem. Needed to change this  - `<MoveItem xmlns="https://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="https://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">` - to this: `<MoveItem xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">`   Thank you!!! (and sorry I totally missed that change in your original answer)